# Post request to Flask using JQuery

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask

Can't figure out where this is going awry, know hardly any `JQuery` which is probably why..

All I'm trying to do is pass a username to a route in `application.py`, so I can query the user table to give it a try (sorry excuse the rhyme it's been a long day)

html & my attempt at jquery:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form novalidate action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" id="idUserName">
            <small id="idUsername" class="form-text text-muted">
                Please enter username
            </small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="idPword1" onkeyup='checkLength()'>
            <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
                Must be 8-20 characters long
            </small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password" type="password" id="idPword2" onblur='checkMatch()'>
            <small id="password2HelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
                Passwords need to match
            </small>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="idSubmit">Register</button>
    </form>

    <script>

        // checkUsername
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#username').on('blur', function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                    data : {
                        userName : $('#username').val(),
                    },
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/checkUser'
                    })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log($('#output').text(data.output).show());
                });
                event.preventDefault();
                });
        });

    </script>
```

`console.log` above doesn't return anything..

The route in `application.py`:

```py
@app.route("/checkUser", methods=['POST'])
def checkUser():
    get_username = request.form['userName']

    return jsonify(output=get_username)
```

Comment: try to print it this way `console.log(data.output);`  this `$("#output").text(data.output).show()`  will change the text of the element with id output and show it (if it was hidden). Also there is no element in your code that has id `output`

Comment: Thanks console.log(data.output) works..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: '',
    url: '',
    data: '',
    success: function (data) {
      // 
      console.log($('#output').text(data.output).show());
    },
    error: function (err) {
      //
    }
  })
```